# Simple auth proxy using Windows Auth

Tags: iis, authentication, iis-7, active-directory

I need to write a very simple authentication proxy service - the user must login via a web browser, then the page redirects the user to another URL if the login was correct.

The server is IIS7; auth is via Active Directory. While I have heaps of experience in Linux, Apache, Python, etc, I have virtually no programming experience in the Windows environment. I understand that IIS can handle the authentication part, but I'm a bit unsure where to start for the generating the URL. What language, environment and resources would be a good starting point?

While one part of me wants to break out the python, another wants to do it 'The Windows Way (TM)'.

Even better would be to use the Windows Domain SSO so the user wouldn't even need to log in, but that can come later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the WISA world (Windows, IIS, SQL, ASP.Net), you can accomplish the above in [ASP.Net Forms Authentication (an option is to use Active Directory)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alvar/archive/2009/02/03/using-asp-net-2-0-forms-authentication-with-active-directory-membership-provider.aspx)

If this is a **private site** (corporate Active Directory intranet) an *easy way* to get *no login prompt at all* (SSO from user AD login on PC) is if you have IE in your network ([NTLM/integrated authentication](http://blogs.iis.net/nitashav/archive/2010/03/12/iis6-0-ui-vs-iis7-x-ui-series-integrated-windows-authentication.aspx)). You can do the security restrictions in IIS for files, folders, etc. without any development - nor would you need ASP.net involved..the files could simply be html, etc. Access is granted in AD in your users/groups to some resource. Although I have never done it, if IIS can run Python, then you can bust out the python :). IE may not be the only choice, it seems you can config [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Integrated_Authentication) - I have not tired this...if its internal/corporate, IE is pretty much the no brainer for it (no sweating/nothing to figure out or tweak).

Comment: Thanks; it does need a small amount of code in order to create a hash for the redirect, but IIS seems to be handling the auth side pretty nicely.